# Will a USB port be able to power a series of LEDs?

Tags: led, usb

I'm planning on having a set of blue LEDs connected in series. I'm looking at having about 30-40 LEDs in series. The power supply will be from a USB 2.0 port mounted on my television. Reading up on the specs for USB 2.0 it has a pin for 5v and ground.

If I used this as my power supply, will my LEDs light up as much as they should or would they be really dim.

The specs for the LEDs are:

- Material : Semiconductor; Light Color: Blue
- Head Dia.: 5mm / 0.197"; Forward Voltage: 3.2-3.4V
- Luminous Intensity: 2000-3000MCD; Wave Length: 460-463
- Size: 24 x 3mm / 0.9" x 0.1"(L*W); Package Content: 50 x Light
  Emitting Diode

And a link to amazon where I purchased is [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005VMDPZ4/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1#productDescription)

Comment: They won't light up at all if they're in series.

Comment: What is the forward volt drop and current required for the LEDs. Your spec is of no use. It's like saying I have a transistor that has three legs and is black.

Comment: @Andyaka He says Blue LEDs so VF in 3-4V range and he also says Vf 3.2-3.4V. Question may have been edited.

Comment: @russell ok thanks dude but he's still missing the current consumption.

Comment: @andyaka if the led specs are missing, assume the typical vf and current limits for the color. Let's not be pedantic about it.

Comment: @Andy True. Looking at link they are blue 5mm. Looking at price they are low life :-) :-(.I think 20 mA sensible max is a very safe bet. If no converter is used then USB_mA = LED_mA. (30 - 40 LEDs ) x 20 mA = 600 - 800 mA. TV "USB" power  MAY supply that. A look at its specs are in order. At say 500 mA you'd get 500/20 = 25 LEDs. At a bit less he'd run his 30-40 at 500 mA.

Answer (score 6):

They definitely won't work from USB if connected in series (even two LEDs in series won't work).

If you connect a ~100 ohm resistor in series with each LED, you may be able to run about five LED/resistor sets connected in parallel from a USB port.  Without negotiation, a USB port is only guaranteed to supply up to 100 mA (although many USB ports have no current control, and may supply 500 mA or more).

According to the comments on Amazon, there is no recommended maximum current data for these LEDs, so I'm guessing 20 mA per LED would be acceptable.

Comment: would connecting them in parallel work instead?

Comment: I did suggest connecting LED/series resistor combinations in parallel, if you read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

40 LEDs in parallel with separate current limit 220R's @ 10mA each is half brightness but 400mA total

> only if you are lucky,  the TV may support this level without enumeration from a smart USB chip. You can test the TV with 12 Ohm >2W resistor before building this using a voltmeter or read TV specs.

Answer (score 0):

5v usb will power 50 parallel group/each group with 2 series led/,i.e 1A/20mA=50 group with 4v drop in each group,  2v drop on each led!
1v drop on a current limiting resistor(1v/1A=1ohm)

Comment: No, the OP specified a forward voltage of 3.2V to 3.4V so you can not use 2 LEDs in series at 5V. Your assumption that 1A is available from a standard USB port is also invalid.